# Use app.config from fsx file

Tags: configuration-files, f#-scripting

Is it possible to use an app.config file from a F# script (fsx) file? If so, how? Where do I put the file and what will it be called?

Comment: Already answered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645622/app-config-and-f-interactive-not-working

Comment: Alternatively here if you have a heavy use of ConfigurationManager in referenced libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150644/change-default-app-config-at-runtime/6151688#6151688

Answer (score 0):

The linked question by @JoeB provides 2 answers which are more suited to F# Interactive than .fsx scripts. I provide a good solution for F# scripts below:

Given this app.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="foo" value="bar"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Read `foo` this way:

```
let appConfigPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "app.config")
let fileMap = ExeConfigurationFileMap()
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename <- appConfigPath
let config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
let foo = config.AppSettings.Settings.["foo"].Value
Console.WriteLine(foo)
```